# Address of a variable

Tags: c

When I code like this and run, the console shows nothing:

```
#include<stdio.h>    
int main()
    {
        int n2= 10;
        int n1= 6;
        int n0= 5;
        int* p = &n1;
        //printf("Address: %p\t%p\t%p\n", &n2, &n1, &n0);
        *p=9;
        p++;
        *p=15;
        p--;
        p--;
        *p=-3;
        printf("n2=%d, n1=%d, n0=%d\n", n2, n1, n0);
        getchar();
        return 0;
    }
```

But when I add

```
printf("Address: %p\t%p\t%p\n", &n2, &n1, &n0);
```

into my code, like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n2= 10;
    int n1= 6;
    int n0= 5;
    int* p = &n1;
    printf("Address: %p\t%p\t%p\n", &n2, &n1, &n0);
    *p=9;
    p++;
    *p=15;
    p--;
    p--;
    *p=-3;
    printf("n2=%d, n1=%d, n0=%d\n", n2, n1, n0);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

It runs in the way I expected (the result of n2 and n0 changed). I don't understand why, can anyone explain it for me?

Comment: Your `p++` and `p--` statements are undefined behaviour. You can't do pointer 'arithmetic' like that on anything other than pointers to elements of arrays. You don't have any arrays. One of the possible manifestations of undefined behaviour is that your program appears to work.

Comment: In the first one, `p++; *p=15;` is undefined behaviour because `p` now points to a different object. It is permitted to point one element past the object, but not to be dereferenced.

Comment: You say 'like this' but I see no changes. Are you sure you posted the good code in the second snippet ?

Comment: See also [When do we casually move out to the pointer region is safe in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69516207/when-do-we-casually-move-out-to-the-pointer-region-is-safe-in-c)

Comment: Actually I just only uncommented a comment from the previous code

Comment: Probably, adding the *printf* cuts some optimizations or otherwise code/data arrangement (compile time) and makes, by luck, the behavior you expect. Don't rely on this.

Comment: The statement `"the program does not run"` is not a very helpful error description. Please describe the exact error.

Comment: Oh, I got it actually it ran but the console shows nothing. I'll edit my post, thank youuu

Answer (score 4):

Variables `n0`, `n1`, and `n2` in your code do not form an array, so you have no guarantee they will occupy a contiguous area in memory. Compilers are not required to allocate them close to each other or in any specific order, they even needn't allocate them in memory - for example a variable may be kept in a processor's register, or even discarded completely if unused.[1]

Hence pointer arithmetics is *not* defined to bring you from one of them to another.

It is an *undefined behavior* what happens then:

- You may hit some vital data of your process and cause the program to crash.
- Or you may hit an inaccessible memory and get your program terminated by the operating system.
- You may be overwriting some unrelated data, important for your code, and thus destroy the order of execution of the program. The result is the program apparently 'working', but doing something else than you designed.
- Or you may hit unused memory and experience completely no change in the program's behavior.

And each of those results may depend on the compiler you used, the machine you run your program on, the kind and version of the operating system. Any change in the program itself or its environment may result in different behavior.

[1]: Except if an address of a variable is explicitly fetched with the `&` operator, which is the case of `n1` in the first version of your code, and all three after you add another `printf()`.

Comment: In practice: as soon as a local variable has its address taken, it gets allocated on the stack on every compiler I've ever used. Therefore it is very likely that all variables in this example are allocated on the stack.

Comment: @Lundin Yes, the `register` optimization, either invoked by a declaration or applied automatically, is disabled for a variable which is used with the 'pointer-to' operator `&`. But in the first version of the code presented only `n1` is used in an `&n1` expression, so this is exception form the compiler's ability to allocate working variables outside the main memory. Anyway, the order of variables and their alignment in memory is still undefined even with all three referenced by `&`, so UB still holds in both versions of code.

Answer (score -1):

**p++** is meaning to change pointer to next address in memory.
This method is incorrect because you are not using arrays.
In some cases, `p++;` may not point to **n0**.

Comment: This is wrong: _'`p++` is meaning to change pointer to next address in memory.'_ Actually, `p++` is meaning to modify the `p` value so that it points to a next consecutive item of the array, to which `*p` belongs (or just past the array, if `*p` was pointing at the last item of the array). This of course involves adresses, but it _also_ involves a _type_ of array's items. But most important, it depends on `p` correctly pointing at some element of a defined array at first. If you use an undefined value in an unitialized variable `p`, the result will be undefined.

Answer (score -2):

Sure.  You are using printf with print format specifiers.

`%p` says you want to print a pointer variable.  It works because the variable in your case is `&n2`.  In this case, `n2` is an `int`, but you take the address of it, making it a pointer with the `&` operator.

`%d` would specify printing a decimal or integer variable.  Don't confuse with `d` for double as in double width floating point number.  See below.

`%f` for a float variable

`%s` a string variable

`%c` a character variable.

See here https://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf for more info

In conclusion you could print the value as an int:

```
printf("n1 is %d \n", n1);
printf("the address of n1 is %p \n", &n1);
```

Comment: Indeed. I corrected it. I use sprintf more than printf. I also know fprintf, sprintf and printf use the same format specifiers.  `$ man 3 sprintf` resolves to same page as `$man 3 printf`, so why worry?